# where are stored obstacles from map?

Tags: navigation, base-global-planner, costmap, map-server, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
I want to check if my path is correct on many maps, so i want to know the position of the obstacles.
The map is provided by map_server ( a picture in black for obstacles and white for empty spaces).

I Was thinking that these values were stored in the cotmap_ of my global_planner but I have checked costmap_.getCost(i,j) for all the position and everything is empty. ( if i sent a goal to my move_base, my robot avoid  the obstacles)

So my question is where are stored obstacles from my map?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190168/where-are-stored-obstacles-from-map?/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 312 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solve my problem. As always in my case it was a stupid mistake.
The things is :

- the funtion getCost(mx,my) don't take meters but cells's coordinate (only positive coordinate).
- the most importante in my case, the zero of the world is not always the center of the map (in my case my map was a little bit smaller).

So global_costmap contain obstacles from the map.

---

Originally posted by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) with karma: 312 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-03**:
Hi, i have a similar question/problem but for the opposite occupancy, i want to extract the FREE cell coordinates of my map and the use them for navigation. do you happen to have a code snip for the free cell export or if can guide to the right path? Thanks a million.

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2015-05-03**:
has I explained if you have a costmap2_d you can use the function getCost(mx,my). This will return you 0 if it's a free cell ( but free cells could have values different than 0 if there are close to an object. --> http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d)

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-04**:
thnx, that part i know. my noob problem is how to index cell coords in the first place, i.e in a vector. are them stored somewhere that can be accessed? and then isolate the FREE cells based on their cost of course. - thanks again for your elaboration.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-05-04**:
@sobot "Comment" is not suitable for asking a new question. You should open a new question referring to this thread.